# Sending data from Windows is slow over any network with high latency but linux is fast

Tags: tcp

Sending data from Windows machine to the Windows or Linux over network with high latency is using 10% of the link capacity. Meanwhile, sending same data over the same network from Linux is almost ten times faster. The issue is same even when high latency is only simulated on the low latency connection by delaying the packets.

It seems that it affects all applications I have tried. Tests were performed on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2003 and the same behaviour was observed.

From tcpdump it is evident that Windows sends about 10 packets in the quick burst and then waits for the ACK, meanwhile Linux sends about hundred packets without waiting for the ACK.

I have tried to enable Compound TCP without improvement.

I am looking for any suggestions on how to find out what is going on. And also how to fix it.

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off-topic for StackOverflow. Please take a few moments to review the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to become more familiar with the types of questions that are (and are not) proper to ask here. Keeping things on-topic helps keep SO a useful *programming* resource. Thanks. :)

Comment: Well it is happening over any LFN, even simulated one with the artificially delayed packets. I was reading FAQ before posting and it seems to me that developers of any network software for Windows have to deal with this issues and therefore it is suitable for the StackOverflow. Did I just phrased it poorly or do you think it is still off-topic?

Comment: It's off-topic. :) IT's a networking question, not a programming question, unless you can post code that's causing you problems. If I ask a question about what kind of computer I should buy, it's off-topic, even if I say I'm using the computer to write code for my programming job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to completely solve my issue by increasing the size of the TCP send and receive buffer in Windows registry (restart is required):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SYSTEM \CurrentControlSet \Services \Afd \Parameters]
DefaultReceiveWindow = 1024000
DefaultSendWindow = 1024000
```

If these keys are not present, the default is 8KB for both which was the amount of data after which Windows was waiting for the ACK.

Also make sure that

```
netsh interface tcp show global
```

does not show

```
Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level    : disabled
```

Otherwise TCP Window Scaling is disabled not only for receiving but also for sending which will significantly limit the connection speed. To enable TCP Window Scaling set Auto-Tuning level for example to normal:

```
netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=normal
```